# how to perform full outer join using tJoin in talend

Tags: talend, full-outer-join

I am trying to implement full outer join using tJoin component but I am not getting as expected results. Could anyone help me on this?

Screenshot of tJoin:

[image: Screen shot of tjoin]

Comment: is the schema of both the joining table is same?

Comment: please go through tMap insteadof tJoin...

Comment: Thanks for ur support we can implement full outer join in tjoin,we need to join left outer and right outer join after that we need combine using with tunite

Answer (score 1):

In fact Talend does not implement a full join, but you can achieve it by reading your inputs twice, performing a left and a right join for each reading, then unite the two flows using `tUnite` and get unique rows by `tUniqRow`

Answer (score 0):

I think tJoin is for LEFT or INNER joins. 
For FULL joins you need to use a tMap.

Regards,
TRF